# How to access the current item of an each block in the controller for a view

Tags: ember.js

Given this controller:

```
ItemController= Ember.Controller.extend({
    subItems: Ember.ArrayController.create({
        content: App.store.find(App.models.SubItem),
        sortProperties: ['name']
    }),

    currentItemIdBinding: 'App.router.mainController.currentItemId',

    item: function() {
        return App.store.find(App.models.SubItem, this.get('currentItemId'));
    }.property('currentItemId'),

    currentSubItems: function () {
        return this.get('subItems.content')
                   .filterProperty('item_id', this.get('item.id'));
    }.property('item', 'subItems.@each')
});
```

and this each block in the template:

```
{{#each subItem in currentSubItems}}
    {{view App.SubItemView}}
{{/each}}
```

How would I gain access to the "subItem" in the controller for the SubItemView?

**Edit:**

I stumbled upon a way to do this. If I change the each block slightly:

```
{{#each subItem in currentSubItems}}
    {{view App.SubItemView subItemBinding="subItem"}}
{{/each}}
```

and add an init method to the SubItemView class:

```
init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.set('controller', App.SubItemController.create({
        subItem: this.get('subItem')
    }));
})
```

I can get access to the subItem in the controller. This however just feels wrong on more levels than I can count.

Comment: +1, I'm also interested in what the "right" way is to have subviews with their own controllers. For single subviews, I've used a computed property on the parent controller and done something like {{view App.SubItemView controllerBinding="subItemController"}} but it does seem odd, and I'm not sure what to tell you for a view with n subviews!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...while browsing [ember.js](/questions/tagged/ember.js), I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14251255/489116 . It's a little different from what you're asking, but may solve the problem: if I'm reading it correctly, it would automatically associate a subItemController with each subItemView and subItem, without you having to pass the model around. Not released yet though. I'd still like to see other solutions!

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Ember.CollectionView` instead of `{{each}}` helper see the following:

```
App.SubItemsView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
  contentBinding: "controller.currentSubItems",
  itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "theTemplateYouUsedForSubItemViewInYourQuestion",
    controller: function(){
      App.SubItemController.create({subItem: this.get("content")});
    }.property()
  })
})
```

Use it in handlebars as follows

```
{{collection App.SubItemsView}}
```